# Spring Programmatic transaction within transaction

Tags: spring, transactions, nested

I have written below code doing below activities 
I created one transaction using Spring classes.
Inserted one row.
Created other transaction.
Inserted another row.
committed outer transaction.
Rolledback inner transaction.

```
TransactionStatus trxstsOuter= dsTrxMngr.getTransaction(null);
    jdbcTemplate.update("insert into kau_emp values(6,'xyz' )");
    TransactionStatus trxstsInner= dsTrxMngr.getTransaction(null);
        jdbcTemplate.update("insert into kau_emp values(7,'pqr' )");

dsTrxMngr.commit(trxstsOuter);
System.out.println("trxstsOuter.isCompleted()" + trxstsOuter.isCompleted());
System.out.println("trxstsInner.isCompleted()" + trxstsInner.isCompleted());
dsTrxMngr.rollback(trxstsInner);
    System.out.println("trxstsInner.isCompleted()" + trxstsInner.isCompleted());
```

I observed that both the rows are committed to DB !!
The output is

```
trxstsOuter.isCompleted()true
trxstsInner.isCompleted()false
trxstsInner.isCompleted()true
```

Is it correct behavior ?
Should not inner transaction be first committed/rollbacked before allowing outer transaction to commit ?
If outer transaction was committed, should rollback of inner thrown an error ?

Comment: There a lot of things  related with the transaction managers(local transaction/container managed/managed transactions /custom transaction managers, transaction propagation, logical transaction/physical transactions, inner transactions, database limitations(nested transactions are not supported by every rdbms) etc. so I would dare to post even any answers :-) this requires many years of learning, and I don't think that the trial and error approach is the way to start :-)

Comment: the transaction is the same as javadoc says

Comment: @BorisTreukhov From debug it is seen that they are different objects, Also from Sysouts of isCompleted() show that they are handled seperately

Comment: @BorisTreukhov You said "nested transactions are not supported by every rdbms" .... I am using HSQL DB. Can it be problem of it ?

Comment: In most apps you just use single transaction, nested db transactions are very advanced stuff which is used very rarely - you should use java entity objects for the state when possible.

Comment: Typically you should manage the state of the entities in objects - for example when transaction is rolled back the ORM will not restore the state of the entities, it will just discard the persistence context. So you should not rely on database to store the transient state of your data in JEE, I believe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example transaction `Propagation.REQUIRED` is used as the default value, and all the logic transactions are mapped to the single physical transaction

> When the propagation setting is PROPAGATION_REQUIRED, a logical
>   transaction scope is created for each method upon which the setting is
>   applied. Each such logical transaction scope can determine
>   rollback-only status individually, with an outer transaction scope
>   being logically independent from the inner transaction scope. Of
>   course, in case of standard PROPAGATION_REQUIRED behavior, all these
>   scopes will be mapped to the same physical transaction. So a
>   rollback-only marker set in the inner transaction scope does affect
>   the outer transaction's chance to actually commit (as you would expect
>   it to).

So in your example two logical transactions are mapped to one physical transaction.

See the [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-programming-model)

Comment: you are right. I printed "trxstsInner.isNewTransaction()" after creating it. It printed "flase".    Later I created inner transaction with PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW. In that case "trxstsInner.isNewTransaction()" was "true" and it did not allow me to rollback inner transaction AFTER i have committed outer transaction. the insert which haapened inside inner transaction was not committed.

Answer (score 2):

In the current code the second getTransaction call is a noop. This behavior is controlled by an attribute called PropagationBehavior.  The default propagation behavior is PROPAGATION_REQUIRED - which means that start a new transaction if none exists or else join the existing transaction.  Which is what is happening in your case.

If you change the propagation behavior attribute for the second transaction to PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW - you will get the behavior you are expected. The outer transaction is suspended and a new transaction is created once the inner transaction is committed/rolled back the outer transaction is resumed automatically.   I have modified your code to incorporate this behavior, you should get an exception now when you try to commit the outer transaction before the inner one.  If you fix the sequence then the commits will happen independently.

```
TransactionStatus trxstsOuter= dsTrxMngr.getTransaction(null);
jdbcTemplate.update("insert into kau_emp values(6,'xyz' )");
    // start a new transaction.
    DefaultTransactionDefinition nestedTransDef = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
    nestedTransDef.setPropagationBehavior(             
           TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);
    TransactionStatus trxstsInner= dsTrxMngr.getTransaction(nestedTransDef);
     System.out.println("trxstsInner.isNewTransaction()"+ trxstsInner.isNewTransaction());  
        jdbcTemplate.update("insert into kau_emp values(7,'pqr' )");

dsTrxMngr.commit(trxstsOuter);
    System.out.println("trxstsOuter.isCompleted()" + trxstsOuter.isCompleted());
    System.out.println("trxstsInner.isCompleted()" + trxstsInner.isCompleted());
    dsTrxMngr.rollback(trxstsInner);
    System.out.println("trxstsInner.isCompleted()" + trxstsInner.isCompleted());
```

As an aside you should be using annotations for managing transactions -that is a much cleaner / nicer way of incorporating transactions in your code.  Programmatic transactions are only for those rare cases where you need more control.  Also while doing programmatic transaction using the TransactionTemplate is recommended.

Comment: I created inner transaction with PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW. In that case "trxstsInner.isNewTransaction()" was "true" and it did not allow me to rollback inner transaction AFTER i have committed outer transaction. The insert which haapened inside inner transaction was not committed

Comment: The above code as I mentioned is not correct. You have to commit / rollback the inner transaction before the outer.  I was expecting that it would throw an exception if you do the other way - but if it is committing the outer transaction then it is bug (but not a critical as it is an incorrect usage of the api)