# programmatic spring transaction within existing transaction

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions

What type of `propagation` is applied when a transaction is invoked programmatically (using `PlatformTransactionManager`) as mentioned [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#transaction-programmatic) within an existing transaction with `REQUIRED` propagation ? Is it `NESTED` or just a logical transaction with `REQUIRED` propagation ?

After going through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786816/spring-programmatic-transaction-within-transaction), it seems its the latter.

Sample Code:

```
DefaultTransactionDefinition def = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
// explicitly setting the transaction name is something that can only be done programmatically

TransactionStatus status = txManager.getTransaction(def);
try {
    // execute your business logic here
}
catch (MyException ex) {
    txManager.rollback(status);
    throw ex;
}
txManager.commit(status);
```

How to find the Propagation behavior and the Isoloation Level from the Transaction Status ? Is there a way ?